# Cannot set up Arduino on Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, arduino

Never been able to get past the following message: "Cannot find Arduino IDE. Please specify the "arduino.path" in the User Settings. Requires a restart after change."
I realize that it is my error in not knowing how to get the extension set up properly and addressing the Arduino/command path correctly, but I have tried everything that seems correct, including reinstalling Arduino IDE and VSC app, paths tried `/Applications` and `/Applications/arduino`. Running on a MacOS.
Thanks for help in understanding the Macintosh path language.

Comment: We don't know what "everything" is, so you must list everything that you have tried. Please use the EDIT button to improve your question.

Comment: Edit your question to include the contents/value of [**arduino.commandPath** and **arduino.path**](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/840).  Without this information, I cannot answer your question.

Comment: According to the documentation, the extension should auto-detect the correct values. Did you do something special when installing the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Nothing special. I have been running Arduino as an IDE for a few years, but not as a component of VSCODE. That is where I am getting into problems. Trying a full delete and reinstall of VSC, I thought, would prompt me or automatically find the Arduino path(s). But not so.

Comment: Deleting the application rarely removes settings. // You can check [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/blob/master/src/common/sys/darwin.ts) in `resolveArduinoPath` where the extension is looking for the IDE.

Comment: Thanks; is this to be executed from within VSC or Arduino.ide?

Comment: It is not “to be executed”. That’s literally the source code of the VS Code Arduino extension. You already have it. // Remove your settings and try again.

Comment: Got it working by deleting a kext file.